# How to enable Gmail Api with Android

Tags: java, android, gmail, android-volley, gmail-api

Hi There  i have problem with gmail api after i have create a new  project on google developer console
then i have enable the gmail api and i had establish the OAuth2.0 key for  the api
and then i have enable the sign in with google in my app but the problem that  i cant get any data from gmail account for the signin users
please help me or provide any advice to help me
This is my code

```
package com.example.spamfilteringusingai_2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.util.ExponentialBackOff;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
   GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
  private  static final int RC_SIGN_IN=9001;
   private static final String[] SCOPES = {
           GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS,
           GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE,
           GmailScopes.GMAIL_INSERT,
           GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY,
           GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY,
           GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM
   };
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
               getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
               .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
       GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
               .requestEmail()
               .requestScopes(new Scope(GmailScopes.GMAIL_SEND),
                       new Scope(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY),
                       new Scope(GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE))
              
       .requestServerAuthCode("884385265121-b0gtdrn1s0dkn2u1vk8m6qlp98mg5s5j.apps.googleusercontent.com")
.build();
       mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
   }
   public void onLoginButtonPressed(View view){
       signIn();
   }
   private void signIn() {
       Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
       startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
   }
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
           Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
           handleSignInResult(task);
       }
   }
   private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
       try {
           GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
           // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
           Log.w("info", "Done" +account.getServerAuthCode());
           Log.w("info", "Done" +account.getId());
           Log.w("info", "Done" +account.getEmail());
           Log.w("info", "Done" +account.getDisplayName());
           Log.w("info", "Done" +account.getAccount());
           String url="https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/joshaer17@gmail.com/messages";
           RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
           StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(String response) {
                   Log.d("respos",response);

               }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                   Log.d("respos",error.toString());

               }
           });
       } catch (ApiException e) {
           Log.w("info", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusMessage());

       }
   }
}
```

Thanks for All